# Redirect user to unknown source page in Android

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I'm developing an app store inside my android app from my company.

When the user didn't activate the **Unknown sources** I redirect him in the right settings page.

Currently I'm doing this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_SECURITY_SETTINGS);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

But in Android O, the setting for allowing Unknown sources has moved in the **Special app access** section.

[image: Special app access]

Do you know a way for sending the user here, or better redirect him directly in this special settings, like in the screenshot below.

[image: Install unknown apps]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I find in this [Google blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/making-it-safer-to-get-apps-on-android-o.html) that you can launch this page directly, you have to use the [ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES) value in your intent. Then you can pass him your package name.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_UNKNOWN_APP_SOURCES);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + context.getPackageName()));
```